# I am running a win form app in RDP and the focus to next text box is not set when I press tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a **win form application** with login screen which runs fine with no issues when run on any machine locally.

But when I RDP to a remote system and run the app in remote system **through RDP**, I face following focus related issue.

**Steps to generate the issue**:

I run the app and that shows login screen with cursor focused on Username field.

I enter the Username and the login screen looks like:

[image: Login screen with focus on Username field]

Now when I press **Tab** key, the cursor stays in Username field and does not move to the password field.

Even though the focus is not on Password field, I key in the password. After inserting the password the login screen still looks as depicted in above screen.

Now when I **click on the app icon** in taskbar, the login screen suddenly has the password available in Password field which I inserted in previous step and it looks as below: (*`So I think when I press **Tab** key in Username field the cursor does move to password field and the password that I type in is also being written to the field but those are not reflected in UI until I press the app icon in taskbar`*)

[image: Login screen with password]

Similar behavior occurs in password field that I have in user screen which allows user to change their password.

If anyone has came across above behavior, please share the cause and solution of the issue.

Thank you for going through the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity did you try to run another app on RDP machine to see you experience similar issues? It sounds like your connection is poor and your screen is lagging.

Comment: No I have not tried the same on any other app. Definitely the connection is not issue as the cursor moves swiftly across other fields except a password field. As I have mentioned the same issue occurs on my user screen as well where I have 7 fields on the form including password field. Pressing Tab moves through all fields but it stops when it reaches the password field.